# SWT Button and information bar Alighnment

Tags: java, layout, swt, jface

I am working on the SWT,with the following code I got the UI as shown in figure(1).In My application information bar appears only certain situations and I am trying to make all three buttons to be aligned always right-side.

```
GridData gridData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false);
Composite comp = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
comp.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, false));
comp.setLayoutData(gridData);
infoArea = new InformationArea(comp, "Example 5");
infoArea.create();
infoArea.setRowLimit(2);
infoArea.setVisible(false);
buttonComposite = new Composite(comp, SWT.NONE);
buttonComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, false));
gridData = new GridData(SWT.END, SWT.BOTTOM, true, false);
gridData.horizontalSpan = 1;
buttonComposite.setLayoutData(gridData);
if (isAddingNewNode() && stepNode.getParent() == null) {
addButton = new Button(buttonComposite, SWT.PUSH);
addButton.setText("Add"));
gridData = new GridData(SWT.END, SWT.BOTTOM, false, false);
gridData.widthHint = 80;
addButton.setLayoutData(gridData);
addButton.setEnabled(false);
}
okButton = new Button(buttonComposite, SWT.PUSH);
okButton .setText("Ok"));
gridData = new GridData(SWT.RIGHT, SWT.BOTTOM, false, false);
gridData.widthHint = 80;
okButton.setLayoutData(gridData);
okButton.setEnabled(false);
okButtonPressed = false;

cancelButton = new Button(buttonComposite, SWT.PUSH);
cancelButton.setText("Cancel")
gridData = new GridData();
gridData.widthHint = 80;
cancelButton.setLayoutData(gridData);
cancelButton.setEnabled(true);
cancelButtonPressed = false;
```

I tried with modifying grabAccessHorizonalSpace in line(gridData = new GridData(SWT.END, SWT.BOTTOM, false, false);)( 3rd Parameter)   to false like below but got the result as in figure (2) and figure (3)

```
buttonComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, false));
gridData = new GridData(SWT.END, SWT.BOTTOM, false, false);
gridData.horizontalSpan = 1;
```

I am trying to build the UI shown  in Figure(4)[image]

[image]

Comment: Any feedback to my answer?

Comment: Thanks! Parent composite properties  dominating so Unfortunately I was not able apply the below. However below answer helped me to think on right way.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you an idea how to achieve what you want:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell();
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, false));

    final Label information = new Label(shell, SWT.CENTER);
    information.setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_GRAY));
    information.setText("Some information text");
    information.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false));

    String[] buttons = {"Add", "OK", "Cancel"};

    for(String text : buttons)
    {
        Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
        button.setText(text);
        button.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.END, SWT.CENTER, false, false));
    }

    Button hide = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
    hide.setText("Hide/Show");
    hide.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.CENTER, SWT.CENTER, true, false, 4, 1));
    hide.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event arg0)
        {
            information.setVisible(!information.getVisible());
        }
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.setSize(500, shell.getSize().y);
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Looks liks this:

[image]

[image]